# How do I perform a Many-to-Many relationship aggregation in SQL?

Tags: sql, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I have data where one value in COLUMN_A can correspond to many values in COLUMN_B, and vice versa. A small example:

```
 COLUMN_A  | COLUMN_B
 ===================
     A     |    X
     A     |    Y
     A     |    Z
     B     |    Y
     B     |    Y
     C     |    X
     C     |    X
     D     |    X
     D     |    Z
     D     |    Z
```

What I would like to see is how many unique instances in COLUMN_A correspond to a unique instance in COLUMN_B. So I would like my output to be like so:

```
 COLUMN_B | # INSTANCES OF COLUMN_A | VALUES IN COLUMN_A
 =======================================================
     X    |            3            |         A    
     X    |            3            |         C    
     X    |            3            |         D 
 -------------------------------------------------------  
     Y    |            2            |         A   
     Y    |            2            |         B
 -------------------------------------------------------
     Z    |            2            |         A  
     Z    |            2            |         D
```

I can't seem to figure out if it's a GROUP BY, a type of JOIN, or some combination of both.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate by column_b in the table and join it to the original table to get the corresponding values in column_a.

```
SELECT t.column_b,
       t.cnt,
       tn.column_a
FROM
  (SELECT column_b,
          count(*) cnt
   FROM tablename
   GROUP BY column_b) t
JOIN tablename tn ON t.column_b = tn.column_b
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a correlated sub-query to do the counting:

```
select distinct column_b,
                (select count(distinct ca) from tablename t2
                 where t1.column_b = t2.column_b),
                column_a
from tablename t1
order by column_b, column_a;
```

Answer (score 0):

By using Simple Partition

```
    DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
        (COLUMN_A varchar(1), COLUMN_B varchar(1))
    ;

    INSERT INTO @Table1
        (COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B)
    VALUES
        ('A', 'X'),
        ('A', 'Y'),
        ('A', 'Z'),
        ('B', 'Y'),
        ('B', 'Y'),
        ('C', 'X'),
        ('C', 'X'),
        ('D', 'X'),
        ('D', 'Z'),
        ('D', 'Z')
    ;


select  COLUMN_B,
        COUNT(COLUMN_B)OVER(PARTITION BY COLUMN_B  )RN ,
        COLUMN_A 
    FROM @Table1
        GROUP BY 
         COLUMN_A,
         COLUMN_B
```